# Move sprite to few points, after first move?

Tags: c++, vector, move, sfml

i developing a simple robot simulator in C++ and SFML.
It looks now like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJyme.jpg)

Yellow and black stripped object is my robot.
I want to move him by path to end of surface, after first move by vector i have problem with another move.
Move method looks like this:

```
sf::Vector2f Robot::moveVectore(sf::Vector2f start, sf::Vector2f end, float t){
if(start == end) return sf::Vector2f(0,0);
// policzenie wektora przesunięcia i jego długości
sf::Vector2f offset = sf::Vector2f(end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y);
float length = sqrtf(offset.x * offset.x + offset.y*offset.y);
// normalizacja wektora
offset = sf::Vector2f(offset.x / length, offset.y / length);
offset.x *= t;
offset.y *= t;
return offset;}
```

And it works used in this way:

```
if(robot1.getDistance(145, 300) > 0.1f){
        sf::Vector2f offset1 = robot1.moveVectore(robot1.tempPositionVector(), sf::Vector2f(145,300), delta*speed);
        robot1.robot.move(offset1);
    }
```

getDistance method give a vector among temporary postition of robot and end point.
My question is how to add more moves to this scene?

Comment: We're missing information here. Like details about what the problem actually is and what currently is working. Additionally a complete but minimal example would help a lot as well.